# is there a base of synonumus dictionaries for solr?

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm looking for english and polish synonymus dictionary for solr. Is there some base of this ? I'm sure I'm not the only one. I was looking for some time but I didn't find anything usefull

Comment: which version of solr are you using? if you are using 5.0/5.1 then you will find it at solr5.0.0/server/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf...  But the file does not include much in it only sample data...

Comment: check if this link is helpful...http://www.quora.com/Apache-Solr/Synonyms-txt-where-can-I-download-an-example-for-English-synonyms